# how to update pinia states of two diffrent stores at the same time?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, supabase, pinia

In want to initialize the states of two differents stores in my "pinia|supabase|quasar|vue 3" app

I try to launch the initializazion of the states from within my component with

```
onMounted(() => {
  settingsStore.getSettings();
  serviceStore.getAllServices();    
});
```

When tested individually, it is updating their respective states.
However when it is fired together, only the last function state is being updated, and the first is being reinitialized.
I made a console log each time the action is called to check and it's ok.
it seems to me that each time i update the state of the last store, it reinitializes the state of the first store.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pinia stores are completely independent by design - one store can not implicitly access another store. This can happen only explicitly - if you import the first store into the second and mutate it or if some Vue component imports both stores and mutates them both - e.g. in a lifecycle hook.

Comment: this is what i thougt, but it appears tha when the second action is fired, the state of the second is always reinitialized.

Comment: for now, i just created a global super store, with the differents stores and actions inside it. and when i fire the two actions for the same store, it's updating the two states. but the organisation is better with modules, and i am still searching for solutions.